# After baking smoke simulation in 2.78 it is no longer able to render on the GPU

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu

I have a simple smoke simulation that I have baked. Before baking, I was able to render frames on the GPU. After baking, it only displays black.

Any idea why this is happening?